# Sql Query for below problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

i have one table having data as mentioned below:

```
  Name
  ----
  ram
  ram
  ram
  sita
  sita
  sita
```

now i need out put like below:

```
ram
sita
ram
sita
ram
sita
```

is any one know the answer?

Comment: This is very little to go on. Please provide a bit more detail, table structure, the query you are currently using, related tables, etc...

Comment: What's your exact criteria? What if `Name` is neither `ram` nor `sita`?

Comment: -1, that is a very poorly formed question. It gives us nothing with which to answer you.

Comment: I think he wants all the first occurrences of every value, then all the 2nd, etc

Comment: name is column name and this is only one column in table.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the analytic function ROW_NUMBER():

```
select name from 
    ( select name
             , row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as rn
      from your_table
order by rn, name
/
```

You will need a column to order the names: I've proposed ID but don't know what columns your table has.

---

The above is the Oracle syntax.   [T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)  may support different syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @T table(Name varchar(5))

insert into @T values
('ram'),
('ram'),
('ram'),
('sita'),
('sita'),
('sita')

select Name
from @T    
order by row_number() over(partition by Name order by Name), Name
```